# Trouble Removing User from SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a user that I added to SSRS 2012 while I was developing the report server.  I gave this user browser permissions in SSRS Report Manager during testing underneath their domain\username.  However, I'm ready to deploy SSRS to production and I'm moving all my users under domain groups.  I've removed all permissions for this user from SSRS Report Manager. I've deleted this user from site settings, folder settings and all folders and files; however, they still have complete access to SSRS.  This user doesn't have permissions on the SSRS server or in the database.   So, I'm not sure how this user still has access.

I'm trying to figure out where I missed removing this user from.   Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you granted permissions to any AD groups?

Comment: No, I haven't granted permissions to anyone except myself as the administrator.  All other permissions have been removed the SSRS Report Manager.

Comment: Is the user also an administrator?

Comment: Is there some caching taking place?

Comment: He was an administrator in report manager but his credentials have been removed.  He never had login rights to the actual server.